# Traversing backwards using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a code like below

If I click the "finallink" class, i want to select or display  all previous elements that matches "level_" class until the "parent" class. There are so many "level" classes like "level_1, level_2... level_n.

​

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="level_0">level 0 text</a>

    <div class="someclass">1</div>
    <div class="someclass">2</div>
    <div class="someclass">3</div>
    <div class="someclass">4</div>

    <h1 class="level_1">level 1 text</h1>

    <div class="someclass">1</div>
    <div class="someclass">2</div>
    <div class="someclass">3</div>
    <div class="someclass">4</div>

    <h2 class="level_2">level 2 text</h2>

    <a href="#" class="finallink">link</a>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I tried something like this

```
$(".finallink").closest("h3").prevAll("level_1").css("background-color","yellow");
```

How Do I get all "level_" values. Example code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpuCb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said the "previous" levels, by which I mean the ones prior to the link. You've said "until the `parent` class" and as that's the *container*, that means we can use all previous siblings and then filter to just the ones with one of the `level_x` classes:

```
$(".finallink").click(function() {
    var list = $(this).prevAll().filter(function() {
        return this.className.match(/\blevel_/);
    });

    // Use `list`
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/etivuq/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/etivuq/1/edit)

This works even if you end up with other classes in front of `level_1`, e.g. `<h2 class="something level_1" ...>`.

Comment: Thanks...This works very well for me. But if I use the ul list, then it doesn't work as expected. Please check the code here http://jsfiddle.net/xpuCb/6/

Comment: @Ra.: Just look at your structure and pick the right tools from [the traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to do what you need. Your fiddle doesn't work because the structure is different from the structure in your question. It's like navigating anything else. Your question's structure is like a single floor in an office block. You're in office A and you've asked how to find office B and office C on the same floor, so that's what I answered. But in your fiddle, office B is one floor up and office C is two floors up. Naturally that changes how we get there.

Comment: I just add parents() function before the prevAll(). Now its works for me. Please check here http://jsfiddle.net/xpuCb/11/

Comment: Is there any way to store the output in to different variables like $var1=somevalue1, $var2=somevalue2

Comment: @Ra.: Of course. Each element for which the `this.className.match(/\blevel_/)` condition is true in the `filter` call is one of the elements. You can grab information about them individually as you go.

Answer (score 3):

If the markup is like the question, where the `finallink` is the last element, or at least does'nt have any elements with a `_level` class below it within the same parent, you could first get the closest parent matching the `.parent` class, then `find()` all elements that matches the `_level` class:

```
$(".finallink").closest(".parent")
               .find("[class^='level_']")
               .css("background-color","yellow");
```

Otherwise, you could do:

```
$(".finallink").prevAll()
               .filter("[class^='level_']")
               .css("background-color","yellow");​
```

Comment: While that will work with the quoted HTML, as soon as the OP changes things *slightly* by adding another class to the levels like this: `<h1 class="special level_1">level 1 text</h1>` it breaks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Was just adding that to the answer myself, but thank you for noticing!